# Running specs throws "Mysql2::Error: Table 'test_db.xxx' doesn't exist: TRUNCATE TABLE xxx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Using Rails 3.1.x, DatabaseCleaner gem and capybara 2, I get the following when trying to run the tests:

```
 Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   Mysql2::Error: Table 'teambox_test_default.incoming_emails' doesn't exist: TRUNCATE TABLE incoming_emails
 # ./config/initializers/connection_fix.rb:24:in `execute'
 # -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 15):

This is solved by running:

```
bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
```

Comment: Thanks micho, I was exepriencing the same issue and this helped create some green in my rspec. However, now I am getting:      Failure/Error: recommendation =     FactoryGirl.create(:recommendation_with_associations, m.to_sym => nil)
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `to_date' for #<Hash:0x007fea4842aa38>